# Tkinter - Using Variables

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a board game using Tkinter.

I've set up a button and a dice that displays a random number (from 1 - 6).

I would like to use that random number to also keep track of each player's position on the board.

How can I assign the random number to a variable and so I can use it outside of the function?

Currently, each time I click the button, the dice displays a new random number on the GUI and the number is printed to the terminal.

Thank you.

```
# Dice
list1 = ["\u2680", "\u2681", "\u2682", "\u2683", "\u2684", "\u2685"]

def dice_click():
    rand = random.choice(list1)
    Label(text=rand, font=('Helvetica 50')) .grid(row=6, column=15, rowspan=2, columnspan=2)
    if rand == "\u2680":
        print(1)
    elif rand == "\u2681":
        print(2)
    elif rand == "\u2682":
        print(3)
    elif rand == "\u2683":
        print(4)
    elif rand == "\u2684":
        print(5)
    elif rand == "\u2685":
        print(6)

dice_button = Button(root, text="Roll", command=dice_click) .grid(row=8, column=15)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a 'scope issue', meaning that Python is doing as intended. When your variable is within a function, it is by default unreachable outside the function.

You could define it as a `global`, or move the random function outside the scope. Simply appending `global` in front of the variable will make it accessible from any scope. However, in your case, I'd recommend you define the random variable outside the function.

Comment: I like the idea of generating the random variable outside of the function. But not sure how to have it generate a random again, when the button is clicked. The idea is to roll the dice several times, and use each roll to move the pieces on the board. Altaf Shaikh also suggested global variables, but I couldn't get that to work properly either.

Comment: I'd consider creating a new function that just generates the random number and another function that retrieves last used random. That seems like the optimal idea

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've decided to pass the random numbers, as they are generated, directly from inside the function to a method in the class that has the logic for the board game. From there I can make the players move around the board, each time the dice is rolled.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your code snippet - you need to use the random number outside this function, but after every time a new random number is generated using dice_click function.

There are 2 ways through which this can be achieved.

1. Using a global variable that you assign the random value to.

```
    `# Dice
    global curr_random
    
    list1 = ["\u2680", "\u2681", "\u2682", "\u2683", "\u2684", "\u2685"]
    
    def dice_click():
        global curr_random
        rand = random.choice(list1)
        Label(text=rand, font=('Helvetica 50')) .grid(row=6, column=15, rowspan=2, columnspan=2)
        if rand == "\u2680":
            print(1)
        elif rand == "\u2681":
            print(2)
        elif rand == "\u2682":
            print(3)
        elif rand == "\u2683":
            print(4)
        elif rand == "\u2684":
            print(5)
        elif rand == "\u2685":
            print(6)
    
        curr_random = rand
    
    dice_click()
    
    # Use curr_random for something else.
```

2. Returning the variable from the function

```
# Dice

list1 = ["\u2680", "\u2681", "\u2682", "\u2683", "\u2684", "\u2685"]

def dice_click():
    rand = random.choice(list1)
    Label(text=rand, font=('Helvetica 50')) .grid(row=6, column=15, rowspan=2, columnspan=2)
    if rand == "\u2680":
        print(1)
    elif rand == "\u2681":
        print(2)
    elif rand == "\u2682":
        print(3)
    elif rand == "\u2683":
        print(4)
    elif rand == "\u2684":
        print(5)
    elif rand == "\u2685":
        print(6)

    return rand

curr_random = dice_click()

# Use curr_random for something else.
```

You can use whichever you like according to your use case and the structure of the rest of the code.

Comment: I tried using a global variable. But the problem is when I insert dice_click() outside the function, I get just the first random number when I first run the application. But I can't capture the other numbers, as I click the button.

Comment: If the flow of your code is structured in such a way that first you press the button, then dice_click is called, and then you are updating the new number in place of the previous one on the tkinter screen, then it should work fine. Maybe you could share the snippet from where you are pressing the button, or the flow of the code in general.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've decided to pass the random numbers, as they are generated, directly from inside the function to a method in the class that has the logic for the board game. From there I can make the players move around the board, each time the dice is rolled.